# SQL Query for all pairs of elements that are only in different groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **Survey** with a *Group* Column and a *Subject* Column

```
CREATE TABLE survey (
  `group` INT NOT NULL,
  `subject` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX (`group`, `subject`)
);

INSERT INTO survey 
  VALUES
  (1, 'sports'),
  (1, 'history'),
  (2, 'art'),
  (2, 'music'),
  (3, 'math'),
  (3, 'sports'),
  (3, 'science')
;
```

I am trying to figure out a query that will return all pairs of subjects that are not part of the same group. So from my above example, I would like to see these pairs returned in a table:

```
science - history  
science - art  
science - music  
history - math  
sports  - art  
sports  - music  
history - art  
history - music
```

Thus, the query shouldn't return:

```
sports - history
```

as an example since they are both in Group 1.

Thanks so much.

Comment: What database system and which version?

Comment: You have "sports" twice in the original data. Or maybe that is the problem with the query you are trying?

Comment: Oh, I am using MYSQL the latest version I think 5.5 release

Comment: Sports being a part of two groups is valid in the case where a person in a different group both happened to like Sports.

Comment: Would you use SQL to describe the Survey table structure and contents? [Code is usually better](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) than natural language.

Comment: The answer can be resolved with cursors or functions, but for an example, we need the db system.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the project?

Comment: @Paul - If "Sports being a part of two groups is valid" then, from the information you have shown, `sports - history` will be returned as `sports` has a group of 1 or 3 and `history` has a group of 1. 1!=3 therefore you will have `sports - history` in your result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.subject,
       s2.subject
FROM   survey s1
       JOIN survey s2
         ON s1.subject < s2.subject
GROUP  BY s1.subject,
          s2.subject
HAVING COUNT(CASE
               WHEN s1.groupid = s2.groupid THEN 1
             END) = 0
```

Comment: The query plan for this query suggests it's the best performing.

Comment: This worked perfectly as well with my database and produced the correct output.  Very fast.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sample table

```
create table Survey(groupid int, subject varchar(100))
insert into Survey select
1, 'sports' union all select
1, 'history' union all select
2, 'art' union all select
2, 'music' union all select
3, 'math' union all select
3, 'sports' union all select
3, 'science'
```

The ANSI-compliant query, which works for all mainstream RDBMS

```
select a.subject, b.subject
from (select distinct subject from Survey) A
inner join (select distinct subject from Survey) B on B.subject > A.subject
left join Survey C on C.subject = A.subject
left join Survey D on D.subject = B.subject and D.groupid = C.groupid
where D.groupid is null
order by a.subject, b.subject
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM yourtable) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT subject FROM yourtable) AS T2
ON T1.subject < T2.subject
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM yourtable T3
    JOIN yourtable T4
    ON T3.id = T4.id
    WHERE T1.subject = T3.subject
    AND T2.subject = T4.subject
)
ORDER BY t1.subject, t2.subject;
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see the difference in performance, although `That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.` - http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Hello, This query worked perfectly.  Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: I am currently looking at the others. I think they are good too but shall confirm asap.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way would be to use `MINUS` to get the complement of all pairs that are in the same group, but [MySQL doesn't support `MINUS`](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71). For MySQL, you can transform a `MINUS` into a statement based on the `NOT IN` operator and a sub-query:

```
SELECT s1.subject, s2.subject
  FROM survey AS s1
    JOIN survey AS s2
  WHERE (s1.subject, s2.subject) NOT IN
  (
    SELECT s1.subject, s2.subject
      FROM survey AS s1
        JOIN survey AS s2
          ON s1.group = s2.group
  )
;
```

Note that this can produce duplicates. If you don't want them, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

With indices and the sample data, the extended query plan is:

> ```
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
> | id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra                                       |
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
> |  1 | PRIMARY            | s1    | index  | NULL          | group | 54      | NULL               |    7 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary                |
> |  1 | PRIMARY            | s2    | index  | NULL          | group | 54      | NULL               |    7 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer |
> |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s1    | index  | group         | group | 54      | NULL               |    7 |    85.71 | Using where; Using index                    |
> |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | s2    | eq_ref | group         | group | 54      | test.s1.group,func |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index                    |
> +----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------+-------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+---------------------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: Are you missing a JOIN condition or is that deliberate and valid in MySQL?

Comment: @Martin: deliberate and valid. The conditionless join produces the universal set, the inner statement produces the set to complement.

Comment: `MINUS` is Oracle specific; the ANSI syntax is `EXCEPT ALL`: http://explainextended.com/2010/02/10/sql-server-except-all/

Comment: @Martin: MySQL is the only one I know of that converts a JOIN without criteria into a CROSS JOIN/cartesian product.

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: I wasn't aware that Oracle supported tuples -- MySQL was the only one I knew about.

Comment: Yay compound-valued expressions!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select S1.Subject As LeftSubject
    , S2.Subject As RightSubject
From SourceData As S1
    Join SourceData As S2
        On S2.subject > S1.subject
    Left Join   (
                Select S1.groupid
                    , S1.subject As LeftSubject
                    , S2.subject As RightSubject
                From SourceData As S1
                    Join SourceData As S2
                        On S2.groupid = S1.groupid
                            And S2.subject > S1.subject
                ) As Z
        On Z.groupid = S1.groupid
            And Z.LeftSubject = S1.subject
            And Z.RightSubject = S2.subject
Where Z.groupid is null
```

Another variant using outis' tuple format:

```
Select S1.Subject As LeftSubject
    , S2.Subject As RightSubject
From SourceData As S1
    Join SourceData As S2
        On S2.subject > S1.subject
Where (S1.groupid, S1.subject, S2.subject) Not In (
                                                Select S1.groupid
                                                    , S1.subject
                                                    , S2.subject
                                                From SourceData As S1
                                                    Join SourceData As S2
                                                        On S2.groupid = S1.groupid
                                                Where S2.subject > S1.subject
                                                )
```